# How to use gulp.js to minimize wordpress css and javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a very simple question. I started using gulp.js to reduce css / javascript files. Now I wondered if it was possible to minimize all files (css and javascript). The intention is that the css and javascript files are simply overwritten and not put in a separate folder if they are minimized :)

Comment: can you post your gulp configuration code here? think you will need to set the gulp target to it's source file...

Comment: `var gulp = require('gulp')
, minifyCss = require("gulp-minify-css");
 
// task
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    gulp.src('*') 
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('*'));
}); `

Comment: you are targeting just everything with `*`. this is quite unspecific and might lead into this unexpected behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure gulp's target to be same as the source.

But in general it's good practice to have separate files.

*Example:*

```
var gulp = require('gulp') , 
   minifyCss = require("gulp-minify-css"); 
// task 
gulp.task('minify-css', function () { 
  gulp.src(['css/main.css','css/second.css',]) 
  .pipe(minifyCss()) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/minified/'));
 });
```

Me personally i just use a caching plugin for Wordpress which does aggregation and minification of JS files. There are plenty.

Comment: How can you do that, is the css is stored in different folders?

Comment: Is it possible to run them through the folders and to reduce and replace the css files (without explicitly indicating where these files are located)?

Comment: you can try like this `gulp.src('css/**/*.css')`. i personally would prefer using a plugin. plugins also care about revisions for [cache busting](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)!